# $Spec(R)$ is irreducible if and only if $Spec(R[T])$ is irreducible

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

I want to show that for an arbitrary ring $R$ the following equivalence holds:

> $Spec(R)$ is irreducible if and only if $Spec(R[T])$ is irreducible.

I have tried to show this by using the characterisation: $Spec(R)$ is irreducible if and only if its nilradical is prime. However, I couldn't show the statement above.

Comment: What's the intersection of all prime ideals in $R[T]$?

Comment: It's the nilradical of $R[T]$.

Comment: If $N$ is the nilradical of $R$, then $N[T]$ is the nilradical of $R[T]$.

Comment: Thank you, could you tell me how to go on?

Comment: Is "the ideal generated by nilpotents is a prime ideal" your definition of $Spec(R)$ irreducible ? In that case there is nothing to prove once $nil(R[T]) = nil(R) R[T], R[T]/nil(R[T]) = R/nil(R)[T]$ an integral domain. To me the question is what happens when $nil(R)$ isn't prime

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $P$ is prime in $R$. I claim that $P[T]$ is prime in $R[T]$. Let $p: R[T] \to R/P[T]$ be the quotient map. This has kernel $P[T]$, and since $P$ is prime, $R/P$ is an integral domain, and therefore so is $R/P[T]$.

Can you specialize this argument to the case $P=nil(R)$?